# Vim like editing in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, vim

Is there a plugin to edit text boxes in Google Chrome with Vim keyboard shortcuts?
I mean without copy pasting the text into a separate window?

Comment: Laziness shouldn't be rewarded, it should be punished.

Comment: I disagree. "Laziness" of this type is one of the things computers are good at, and this kind of thing is possible. See my answer.

Comment: The asker is lazy because he didn't even try to find an answer to his question not because he wants to use vim shortcuts in his browser's textfields. If he had actually searched by himself he would have already found wasavi. It's not like it's hidden or something. You rewarded his laziness and, with all due respect, that's wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [It's All Text for Chrome?](http://superuser.com/questions/261689/its-all-text-for-chrome)

Answer (score 2):

Try this addon, which is available for Chrome, Firefox, and Opera: http://appsweets.net/wasavi/

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at TextEditorAnywhere: http://www.listary.com/text-editor-anywhere
It not only works for the browser, for almost all other applications, too.
It's freeware.